# php split string into html form

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am storing a string in a mysql database in the following format:

```
 $row["actions"]=   Add&&Remove&&Replace&&Change&&
```

I need to splice each one of those into a check box html form for example

```
  while{
    echo  $row["actions"];
     //this would be the string to cut up

     }
for each before && as cut {
     <form action="" method="post">
 //name would be add
      <input type="checkbox" name='$cut[0]' value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
//name would be Remove
 <input type="checkbox" name='$cut[1]' value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
//name would be replace
   <input type="checkbox" name='$cut[2]' value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>}
```

Comment: Add&&Remove&&Replace&&Change&& doesn't seem to have anything to do with your desired output. Please clarify.

Comment: $row[actions] is add remove and that needs to be cut up and for each that would be cut[0] made adjustments @Difster

Comment: `$cut = explode('&&', $row['actions']);`

Comment: It is bad practice to store multiple values in a single column in your database. Please make sure you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Your question is not clear, please let us know what is the expected output look like. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot you just use simple check, since you have pre-defined actions?

```
// If you have "Add" in your string, then print needed string
if (strpos( $row["actions"], 'Add') !== false) {
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name='Add' value=\"Bike\"> I have a bike<br>"
}
//... and so on`
```

And if you really need to split and iterate over your values, then take a look at `explode` function, which does exactly this. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

It is not really clear what you're trying to achieve. As already noted in comment, you should neither:

- Store multiple values in one row in the database \ in one variable
- Have checkboxes for mutually exclusive actions (?). Probably you want radiobuttons here.

Also please note that your code is not a valid PHP code. You cannot mix HTML and PHP like this. So you need either to close PHP tag like `<?php $a=1; ?> <a href="google.com">HTML goes here</a>` or do `echo` or `print`: `echo "<a href=\"google.com\">Some HTML</a>";`